# How do I use Webpack 4 to export vendor CSS

Tags: webpack, vue.js

I am building a small Vue.js project using Webpack 4.

In the style block of my `App.vue` component, I can import `bootstrap.scss` into my `main.js` bundle, then export it to `main.css` using the `mini-css-extract-plugin`.

But if I also have custom styles, the Boostrap (vendor) CSS is mixed together with my custom CSS.

I'm wondering, how can make it export the Bootstrap (vendor) CSS into its own named, hashed chunk? And keep the custom CSS in its own named, hashed chunk?

It looks like you can explicitly name JavaScript imports, with webpackChunkName magic comments:

https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#import-

Similarly, is there a way to explicitly name my Bootstrap CSS import?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional `js` entry point to your app, that will import only `Bootstrap.css`, and name it what ever you want. That will generate css file with that name.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. Is there a way to keep the `bootstrap.js` script tag from getting injected into the `index.html` ?

Comment: It is related to webpack-html-pluhin, you can check with its options, try to check `excludeChunks`

Comment: Thank you for your followup, the  webpack-html-plugin docs opened my eyes and led me to the css-entry plugin, which is a little cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled onto css-entry-webpack-plugin, which enables the clean creation of CSS-only bundles.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-entry-webpack-plugin

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "bootstrap": "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.css",
    "main": "src/index.js"
  },
  output: {
    path: "dist",
    filename: "[name].[hash].js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      // This is required
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: "css-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CssEntryPlugin({
      output: {
        filename: "[name].[hash].css"
      }
    })
  ]
};
```

Unfortunately, this plugin appears to not support Webpack 4 yet...